# Meaning of 'constant T and p'

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equation-of-state

In chemical thermodynamics, the condition "constant temperature and pressure" appears almost everywhere. However, I felt a small ambiguity in the phrase so I wanted to clear my doubts. When we say "constant $T$ and $p$" in chemical thermodynamics, which of these two statements do we actually mean?

- $T$ and $p$ are the same at the beginning and end of the reaction
- $T$ and $p$ are the same throughout the entire reaction

If we care about path-dependent variables, then there is a major difference between the two meanings.

Comment: It means that the temperature and pressure may change during the transformation. But th initial and final values of $T$ and $p$ are the same.

Comment: All time if process-wise, initially and finally if state-wise.

Comment: @Poutnik if that's the case then it's definitely an ambiguous phrase

Comment: @juanperez I suppose it is true, but only if it is cut out of its context and if one is not familiar with TD states and processes. For the starters, they can think constant all the time. When they learn state variables do not depend on the path, they will learn that just states matters.

Comment: The key point is you will have to think whether the process is reversible or irreversible. You will have to be careful with the context.

Answer (score 2):

As a chemical engineer, my perspective on this differs from those of the other responders.  I regard a process occurring at constant temperature *and* pressure as one in which

1. The system is held in contact with a constant temperature over the portion of its interface with the surrounding through which heat transfer is occurring, not necessarily the initial temperature of the system, throughout the process
2. The external pressure (or more precisely, the external compressive stress) at the portion of the system interface with its surroundings at which displacement work is being done is held constant (not necessarily at the initial pressure of the system) throughout the process.

Comment: Why is it enough to know only about the nature of interface for chemical engineers?

Comment: @Burian It may not be enough to solve a specific problem, but it is what we *define* as a constant-temperature process or a constant-pressure process.